# If search results empty then execute certain code

Tags: php, functions, search

If search results are empty then I want that some code be executed, but how to write such situations programmatically?

```
If !is_search() {

certain code

}
```

But above doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will check whether you are on a search page or not ( You also forgot to wrap your conditional in parentheses ).

In order to check if there is any result for your search, use `have_posts()`:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    // There is a post
} else {
    // No results
}
```

This works for global queries. If you wrote your own instance of `WP_Query()`, you need to do as follows:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $my_query->have_posts() ){
    // There is a post
} else {
    // No results
}
```

Comment: sir, do you have any solution to this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285747/wordpress-core-default-sidebar-widgets-should-be-cleared-on-installation-of-a-th)